# In Django, how to index a field on a proxy model's original model?

Tags: django

I have a model that is a proxy model based on [Django Comments'](https://github.com/django/django-contrib-comments) `Comment` model:

```py
from django_comments.models import Comment

class Annotation(Comment):

    # ...

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

The `Comment` model has a `TextField()` called `comment` and I'd like to add a [GinIndex](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/indexes/#ginindex) to this to speed up full text searching using Postgresql.

However, I can't add an index on this field in `Annotation`'s `Meta` class because I get this error:

> annotations.Annotation: (models.E016) 'indexes' refers to field 'comment' which is not local to model 'Annotation'.
>     HINT: This issue may be caused by multi-table inheritance.

And I can't add an index to the field definition itself, because it's in `django_comments`' `Comment` model.

I *guess* I could write a migration to manually add an index to `django_comments.models.Comment`'s `comment` field using SQL, but I wonder if there's some less messy way that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Proxy models are only for changing Python behaviour of models, you cant change database level behaviour (adding fields, changing indexes etc..).

I would not suggest writing migration for an external app in your project, which could get messy because of migration dependencies/orders.

I looked in to the documentation of Django Comments and i think it allows you [customize the Model.](https://django-contrib-comments.readthedocs.io/en/latest/custom.html#an-example-custom-comments-app) You can add index or change anything you want by extending abstract model in your custom comment app.

Comment: Thanks... I'm wary of doing that as this is an existing app with tens of thousands of comments. Hmm. I'll have to have a think about what's best to do.